# Current Sensor Layout

Tags: layout

I'm trying to improve my circuit layout skills. I'm currently working on a board that needs some current sensors. I've included a screenshot of the layout. I'm hoping some gurus out there can point out weaknesses in this design or some things I could do to improve it.

The VDD and GND vias go to solid power planes. The pins to the right of the I2C pins are address select pins. The bottom-middle pin on the IC is the voltage sense pin. A screenshot of the schematic is also included incase that makes it easier to tell what

Thanks in advance

[image: Image1]
[image: Image2]

Comment: What is VB? What is the purpose of Q5? What is the voltage switching level that will be applied to ENB? I am asking because there are frequent mistakes made with this sort of thing. I just want to catch your mistakes (if any) before you go much farther. For example, if VB is ever higher than 3.3V, current will flow through Q5 and there is nothing you can do about it (except measure the current by way of U2). If ENB is less than 3.3V, Q5 may partially (or fully) turn on.

Comment: @mkeith The B refers to channel B. This current sense circuit is one of many on the board. VB is power to Device B and ENB is the enable pin for Device B. ENB is controlled by a 3.3V GPIO on the microcontroller.

Comment: As far as I can tell, all is in order. Thanks for clarifying, though. A lot of people either put their MOSFET backwards, or try to turn off a PMOS with a voltage that is too low (gate 3.3, source 12V or something like that). The only thing for you to consider is what happens during power on. ENB will be in kind of an undetermined state briefly before the processor fully boots and drives it to a known state. Depending on what is connected to VB, this may or may not be OK. Maybe a gate-source pullup or even a cap from gate to source could mitigate this.

Answer (score 1):

Each square of copper foil in a standard-thickness PCB-foil (1 ounce of copper per square foot) has resistance of 0.000498 ohms (0.5 milliOhms).

Your layout has about 50 squares of copper in the high-current paths. At 0.4 amps, that become 50*0.5 milliOHms = 25 millOhms, or 10 milliVolts. Or 4 milliWatts. Not a big deal all distributed like that.

Answer (score 0):

C2 could be placed better, and you could use wider traces for it. I would rotate it by 90 degrees and use a smaller package so it can be closer to the power pins. Though in all honesty it will probably work fine as is.

How much current is going through the shunt? Did you do any calculations to make sure the power trace is wide enough? There are online calculators. Length matters, too.

REVISED
The datasheet for the INA226 says that VBUS can be connected to either side of the shunt. It depends on whether you want to include the power dissipated by the shunt in your calculations, or whether you only want to measure the power delivered to the load. The way you have it connected, you will be measuring load power + shunt power. If that is not what you want, then connect VBUS to the other side of the shunt, and you will be getting load power only. The difference shouldn't be too big either way, because the shunt voltage is small compared to 3.3V.

Answer (score 0):

I would flip components vertically to keep shunt and mosfet as close to power terminals (or whatever "device" you have on top of your PCB) as possible.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your concern about GND and VB? I mean, now that the OP clarified, VB is basically the same as 3.3V (when the FET is switched on). So it is just another power rail. So the OP definitely needs VB separated from GND. The INA226 is designed for high-side sensing, so it should be OK. If I am missing something let me know.

Comment: No, with the clarification from OP it all makes sense now. And it should work just fine. I'll edit my post to remove that.